# Как реализовать сортировку при рендеринге Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте. 
Делаю аналог stackoverflow в учебных целях. Есть страница вопроса (show). В ней рендерятся ответы:

```
.answers_block
  = render @answers
```

Ответы получаю таким методом

```
def get_answers
  @answers = Answer.where(question_id: @question.id).order(created_at: :desc)
end
```

Также есть голосование за каждый ответ. Есть метод который считает "рейтинг ответа"

```
def votes_count(answer)
  @answer = Answer.find(answer.id)
  @votes = @answer.get_upvotes.size - @answer.get_downvotes.size
end
```

Для подсчета голосов использую гем gem 'acts_as_votable'.
Как реализовать сортировку ответов по рейтингу при рендеринге?

Comment: Добавьте к модели поле, в котором будет храниться текущая сумма голосов. При добавлении/удалении голоса, меняйте его значения. При выводе ответов - сортируйте по нему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Э-эх... выкидывайте ваш `votes_count`. Он работает не на уровне БД, а сортировать на стороне Ruby вы **не** хотите, потому что выборку (к примеру, одну страницу) по нему вы сможете делать только на стороне Ruby (или с применением хитроумных техник вроде k-го максимума, что при работе с БД только добавит проблем). Разумеется, вы можете сделать `JOIN`+`COUNT`+`GROUP BY` на голоса, но это будет повторная реализация этого метода на другом языке (SQL). Не круто.

В `acts_as_votable` есть [колонки для кэширования](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#caching), в том числе текущего общего веса голосов:

```
add_column :posts, :cached_weighted_total, :integer, :default => 0
```

...и для сортировки по рейтингу можно просто сортировать по значению этой колонки.

Чтобы оно работало, нужно только [проставить голосам **за** вес `1`, а голосам **против** вес `-1`](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#adding-weights-to-your-votes).

```
@post.upvote_from @user2,   :vote_weight =>  1
@post.downvote_from @user2, :vote_weight => -1
```

Образуется избыточность, т. к. хранятся отдельно веса голосов и их характер (за/против), но это проблема гема в целом: он старается быть как можно более общим. То, что не используется, становится бесполезной избыточностью. Если вам это не нравится, можно:

- Отказаться от механики downvote гема, использовать одинаковые голоса разных весов и использовать нейтральный хелпер (который генерирует голоса **за**, но это не парит):

  ```
  @post.vote_by :voter => @user3, :vote_weight => (positive? 1 : -1)
  ```
- Отказаться от весов, использовать сортировку по `cached_votes_up - cached_votes_down`, и не забыть функциональный индекс (или хотя бы его суррогат в виде колонки и триггеров) по нему, чтобы не считать постоянно
- Отказаться от гема, написать голосовалку самостоятельно

Comment: спасибо, похоже написать свою голосовалку будет проще и быстрее чем переделать этот гем)

Comment: @MaximCherevatov это в целом штука несложная. Но в геме уже решена не очень приятная (хотя и простая) задача кэширования суммы весов. Поэтому смысл пользоваться гемом всё-таки есть.